# Python Line Sorting -

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following:

```
line  = ['aaaa, 1111, BOB, 7777','aaaa, 1111, BOB, 8888','aaaa, 1111, larry, 7777',,'aaaa, 1111, Steve, 8888','BBBB, 2222, BOB, 7777']
```

Is there away I can sort by (Bob,Larry,Steve) then by (1111,2222)?

so...

```
for i in line:
    i = i.split(' ')
    pos1 = i[0]
    pos2 = i[1]
    pos3 = i[2]
    pos4 = i[3]
```

So I need to sort by pos3 and then by pos2.

Desired output would be:

```
'aaaa, 1111, BOB, 7777'
'aaaa, 1111, BOB, 8888'
'BBBB, 2222, BOB, 7777'
'aaaa, 1111, larry, 7777'
'aaaa, 1111, Steve, 8888'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leave the splitting to a key function:

```
sorted(line, key=lambda l: l.lower().split(', ')[2:0:-1])
```

This returns the strings in `line` in lexicographically sorted order, case-insensitive. The `[2:0:-1]` slice returns the third and second columns in reverse order.

Demo:

```
>>> line  = ['aaaa, 1111, BOB, 7777','aaaa, 1111, BOB, 8888','aaaa, 1111, larry, 7777','aaaa, 1111, Steve, 8888','BBBB, 2222, BOB, 7777']
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(sorted(line, key=lambda l: l.lower().split(', ')[2:0:-1]))
['aaaa, 1111, BOB, 7777',
 'aaaa, 1111, BOB, 8888',
 'BBBB, 2222, BOB, 7777',
 'aaaa, 1111, larry, 7777',
 'aaaa, 1111, Steve, 8888']
```

If your 'lines' are not as neatly comma + space separated, you may need to strip whitespace too.

Comment: That doesn't seem to give me the desired output I added above

Comment: @Dumbkid_trying: Made it case-insensitive, fixed the incorrect slice (I missed how you numbered your columns).

Comment: perfect, how is this )[2:0:-1])) splitting it. Just trying to get a better understanding

Comment: @Dumbkid_trying: It is not. `.split(', ')` does the splitting, returning a list. The `[2:0:-1]` takes a slice from that list, in reverse order (the last element `:-1` defines the stride, negative strides count backwards). It starts at index `2`, then counts down to index `0` (which is not included). So in the end a new list is returned containing index `2` and index `1`, in that order.